# Android google sign in

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform

I have implemented a Google login into my Android app from Google Cloud Platform console and it works in the app release but after uploading the app to Google play store it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google sign in signed apk not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045652/google-sign-in-signed-apk-not-working)

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android

Comment: Check your app's log and see if anything related to this issue comes up. If there were any, mention them in your question.

Comment: Fixed it thanks, google generates another sha-1 key on play store in releases management -> app aigning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change your SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from google play console. i thank SHA-1 finger print you can find in the app sign menu of google play console.

Comment: Fixed it thanks, google generates another sha-1 key on play store –