# Android Firebase Auth Google failed code=10 Only on Phone

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication

I have been making an app for android and testing the google login worked fine when I used the emulator and on my phone directly. However, when I *"generate a signed bundle/apk"* and install the app on my same phone or any other phone, I get the following error:

```
D/~google~: signInResult:failed code=10
```

It's happening in this method:

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            Log.d("~google~","successful google login");
            isLoginSuccessful = true;
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.d("~google~", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

I have searched for this answer, but I have not come across a consistent solution, specific to the behavior I'm observing.

Comment: Have you entered you SHA-1 Fingerprint in Firebase ?

Comment: Yes, once I did I was able to validate the login on the emulator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045652/google-sign-in-signed-apk-not-working I guess this may contain your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google sign in signed apk not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045652/google-sign-in-signed-apk-not-working)

Comment: It looks like the SHA1 matches between the google console and android studio, but it does say "debug".

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to answer my own questions, but because I couldn't find the **full solution**  to my problem I wanted to try share what worked for me.

Firstly I kept seeing a lot of answer suggest missing SHA1 or mismatching SHA1 keys, but for those who don't know (as of this date at least) that's the Secure Hash Algorithm. It's basically a long string of HEX code i.e. `FF:AC:00:33:22:03:...` etc etc.

There are two different SHA1 keys that are generated when you're developing: one for *"debug"* and another for *"release"*.  I was able to locate  my SHA1  for both by generating signed apk's:  **Build>Generate Signed APK**

[image]

Select **APK** then **NEXT**

[image]

If you've done this before, you should already have a key store path, key store password, key alias, and a key password. If not be sure to create them then click **NEXT**.

> NOTE : Copy your key store path & the alias and paste it somewhere temporarily. Remember your password.

[image]

Now select **release**.

[image]

Then going to terminal I run the following command for the release SHA1:
`keytool -list -v -keystore <key store path> -alias key alias`

> NOTE : You may have to enter the password.

[image]

Now you can go into your firebase auth by going to your app, clicking on the setting's (gear icon) and going to the **Project Settings**. Scroll to the bottom of the General tab and add the release SHA1 key by clicking **Add Fingerprint** and pasting the SHA1 key in.

[image]

I really hope this helps someone in the future.

> NOTE: I am using Android Studio version 4.1.3